# Is C++ SDL and (Python PyGame) used by people other than hobbyists?

Tags: c++, python, sdl, pygame

As a hobbyists who has a little experience making 2D games using PyGame, and has ventured into using C++ with the SDL library (in Visual Studio), I'm curious. Is the library used professionally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_using_SDL

Doom3 and Unreal Tournament are on that list, so I'd say it is used professionally

Comment: Doesn't seem like any of the big names use it as their primary platform abstraction though.

Answer (score 3):

SDL is used professionally and some great games were made with it. Many times it is used as a cross-platform window creation system to initialize openGL (as I assume it is used for Doom3, UT, etc...). It is also used for as "raw" 2d graphics API (for example in Battle For Wesnoth).